# How to pass my sitecore context page item to apicontroller?

Tags: jquery, api, sitecore

I want to post my sitecore context page item to my controller so that i can use in my controller.i want to do it my post method from my view page.
please help on this how to write post method and ajax call from view.
for example:

i want to pass string id to my controller action method.

```
@{
    var page = Sitecore.Context.Item;
    string id = page.ID.ToString();
 }
```

am trying to write ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var formData = {urlParameter:encodeURI(url)}; //how to add string
$.ajax({
    url: "http:/local/api/cable/sample",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        //handle success
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
         //Handle error
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try to write any ajax call ? If yes add that also in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will help you to understand what you are looking.

```
    $.ajax({
        var id = <Your id value>
        url: "/ControllerName/ActionName?id="+id,
        success: function(data) {
        //Whatever you return from your action
        }
    });
```